# Error when Initializing two firebase Apps within a Single Reactjs project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get this error when I initialize two firebase Apps within my reactjs project.

Uncaught TypeError: r[t] is not a function

My goal is to read/write to [default] firebase.database and write to the second firebase.database named "al".

fb version: 3.7.4;

My config.js file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "my_apiKey_from_fb_default",
  authDomain: "my_authDomain_fb_default",
  databaseURL: "my_databaseURL_fb_default",
  storageBucket: "my_storageBucket_fb_default",
  messagingSenderId: "my_messagingSenderId_fb_default"
};

const configAl = {
  apiKey: "my_apiKey_fb_al",
  authDomain: "my_authDomain_fb_al",
  databaseURL: "my_databaseURL_fb_al",
  storageBucket: "my_storageBucket_fb_al",
  messagingSenderId: "my_messagingSenderId_fb_al"
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const firebaseAl = firebase.initializeApp(configAl, "al");

// Default DB entry point
export const fbDB = firebaseApp.database();
export const fbAuth = firebaseApp.auth();

// Analytics DB entry point
export const fbAlDB = firebaseAl.database();
```

Any ideas what I do wrong?